# Refresh Token in JWT

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, refresh-token

How to get the refresh token in JWT format?
Team is working on authentication using AAD and the OIDC library that is being used expects the tokens to be in JWT for decoding purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh token is not returned in JWT. Applications should not be inspecting a RT as it is only useful for the Authorisation server to issue new Access tokens. RT is an encrypted blob that only the authorisation server can decode for this process.